# Excel: Does there exist a geometric mean if type manipulation in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, match

What Excel formula would one use to if matched on perlbench for the range of the strings on the left; geomean the total of the matched expressions?

```
9898perlbench-683740987    8

9983perlbench-089730897    7

08970897087perlbench999    4

089723487gcc08970987878    3

09870897perlbench98-98i    2

08970789perlbench9080870   9
```

So, the strings all should match 'perlbench' upon query except for the one 'gcc' and return the geomean of 8, 7, 4, 2, 9.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the geomean number part of the string (separated by space)?

Comment: What have you tried and what problem have you run into?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but supposed you want to have the last number of the string under the condition the string contains 'perlbench' you could use this formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("perlbench",A1))),RIGHT(A1,1),"")
```

(The referenced cell is `A1` of course)

UPDATE:

I think now I understood the requirements: So let's say range A1:A6 contains the strings and B1:B6 the numbers. So the filtered geomean could be calculated with:

`=GEOMEAN(IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("perlbench",A1:A6))),B1:B6,""))`

It's IMPORTANT to implement this formula as array formula. To do so, type or paste this formula to Excel's formula bar and don't simply press Return but Ctrl-Shift-Return!!! The formula will now be shown surrounded with curly brackets

Comment: Can A1 be a range instead of a single cell?

Comment: So the string and the number are in different cells?

Comment: So, the cells to the left might have the string 'perlbench' within them and those live in their own cells. The numbers to their right are associated with each string and those have their own cells.

So what I'm looking for is...look over a range of values on the left. If those cells have 'perlbench'...take it's associated number and geomean it with the other string associated numbers that have the word 'perlbench' to yield one geomean.

Comment: Maybe my update is helpful? I don't really know: should the geomean be calculated? And from which of the numbers?

Comment: It's the geomean of all the numbers whose strings contain 'perlbench.'

Comment: What are A1 and B1? Can a range of strings be searched for 'perlbench'?

Comment: Oh I think, now I understand. Do you really need a single formula to calculate all at once? I thought you could use my formula to filter the strings line by line. After that you could calculate the GEOMEAN in a separate cell.

Comment: Exactly :) A single formula would be super helpful.

Comment: You could shorten your formula a bit, and reduce the function count by one,  by replacing `NOT(ISERROR(..` with `ISNUMBER(...`